# Create table with summarization and latest value of the year

Tags: powerbi, dax

For each `ClientNo` I want the `Type` classification corresponding to the last date of each **Year**:

[image]

Thus, the table above should be summarized as:

[image]

So, somehow, we need two intermediate tables:

- Unique values for years, like `VALUES(Table[Date].Year)`
- Unique values for ClientNo, like `VALUES(Table[ClientNo])`

Then for each combination of Year and `ClientNo`, get the latest date for each year and finally get the `Type` classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this in two steps along these lines:

```
Summary =
VAR MaxDates =
    SUMMARIZE (
        ADDCOLUMNS ( Table1, "Year", YEAR ( Table1[Date] ) ),
        Table1[ClientNo],
        [Year],
        "MaxDate", MAX ( Table1[Date] )
    )
RETURN
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        MaxDates,
        "ClientNo", [ClientNo],
        "Year", [Year],
        "Type", LOOKUPVALUE (
            Table1[Type],
            Table1[ClientNo], [ClientNo],
            Table1[Date], [MaxDate]
        )
    )
```

In calculating the variable, we add a `Year` column and then calculate the maximal date corresponding to that year.

Then we take that table variable, pick out the `ClientNo` and `Year` columns, and look up what the `Type` corresponding to the `MaxDate`.

---

If Note: you want to keep the `MaxDate` column, replace

```
[...] SELECTCOLUMNS ( MaxDates, "ClientNo", [ClientNo], "Year", [Year], [...]
```

with

```
[...] ADDCOLUMNS ( MaxDates,  [...]
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexis Olson, I get a lot of syntax errors, still trying to fix them :-)

Comment: I find it very difficult when creating a table in a variable to make a reference to a column of that table.

Comment: It's a bit tricky, yeah, but usually there's a way to work around it.